# HighCharts rest zoom fails on xy

Tags: highcharts, zooming, reset

I have a problem with HighCharts when I set it to zoom on xy. It zooms fine but on the rest, the axes reset but the plot area stays the same. Sometimes takes 2 or 3 goes to break but once it does, it stays broke. My code is below:

```
    $(function () {


        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBorderWidth: 1,
                spacingTop: 0,
                spacingBottom: 0,
                marginRight: 15,
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: "Test",
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: "Year"
                },
                allowDecimals: false
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }],
                labels: {
                    format: '${value:,.0f}',
                    minPadding: 1000
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                useHTML: true,
                headerFormat: '<bold>{series.name}</bold><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:#000000">Year {point.x} : ${point.y:,.0f}</td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>'
            },

            series: [
                     { data: [[1, 805.593193551804], [2, 805.593193551804], [3, 805.593193551804], [4, 805.593193551804], [5, 805.593193551804], [6, 805.593193551804], [7, 805.593193551804], [8, 805.593193551804], [9, 805.593193551804], [10, 805.593193551804], [11, 805.593193551804], [12, 805.593193551804]], name: 'Before', color: '#EDF2DB', type: 'area' },
                     { data: [[1, 805.593193551804], [2, 805.593193551804], [3, 805.593193551804], [4, 805.593193551804], [5, 805.593193551804], [6, 805.593193551804], [7, 805.593193551804], [8, 805.593193551804], [9, 805.593193551804], [10, 805.593193551804], [11, 836.4400689934657], [12, 867.8232333655329]], name: 'After', color: '#FF6600', type: 'column' }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was temporary problem, but in the newest master branch it is fixed.

See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/fZBjS/

```
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.js"></script>
```